# File transfer over unreliable and slow connection with c#

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

I am looking for a way to transfer a lot of files over a long period of time from a client to a server.
The connection between the client and the server is not reliable and slow.

I thought about using the FTP protocol. I saw the [netftp client](https://netftp.codeplex.com/).
I now need a ftp server in .net also.

The most important feature that I need is reliable connection resuming. Something that I can rely on to just start and end over a period of time reliably.

I didn't find many ftp servers that were written in c#.

Thank you.

Comment: A resume state download can be pretty easily integrated in a WCF Service in .net 4.0. There are couple simple example out there.

Comment: I am not sure if its good for files, there are better protocols then tcp for file transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Background Intelligent Transfer Service in windows.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799(v=vs.85).aspx

Use BITS for applications that need to:

1. Asynchronously transfer files in the foreground or background.
2. Preserve the responsiveness of other network applications.
3. Automatically resume file transfers after network disconnects and computer restarts.

a .net wrapper is available for BITS - http://sharpbits.codeplex.com/

Comment: It looks good, I didn't know about it. Do you know if its good with upload resume also?  My main goal is reliable uploading.

Comment: you should be able to resume upload too. you can create a new job and  manage via BitsManager. you can find a working example here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14727/SharpBITS-NET-A-Wrapper-for-the-BITS-API